# Send build artifacts over SSH - could not create directory

Tags: ssh, git, jenkins

I am trying to workout an automation process of pushing changes from jenkins to aws. The problem seems to be that within the GIT repo, i have 2 folders, one is `docroot` and the other is `database`. I need the `docroot` to go into the `/var/www/html` and database should be ignored for now.

As a trial run, i am trying the following settings:

**Settings 1:**

Post-build Actions

Under transfer set

```
Source files: **/*
Remove prefix: empty
Remote directory: empty
Exec command: pwd
```

Result:
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not create or change to directory. Directory [database]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

**Settings 2**:

Post-build Actions

Under transfer set

```
Source files: **/*
Remove prefix: empty
Remote directory: /var/www/html
Exec command: pwd
```

Result:
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Could not create or change to directory. Directory [var]]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE

All the errors seem to be revolving around creation of a directory - but i dont need to create one...

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting?

Comment: @KarenB - its stated above under each settings...